# how to embed an object in another one

Tags: javascript, json

I have

```
let inside = { description: 'some text'};
```

what I need to do is first create a new object from the above

make

```
enhanced = { description: 'some text',
                  fielda: 'a',
                  fieldb: 'b;
                }
```

to accomplish the above I use the spread operator `...`

now what is left to do is transform enhanced to have an outer key
such as

```
enhancedOuter = 
    { item: 
         description: 'some text',
         fielda: 'a',
         fieldb: 'b
    }
```

any thoughts on how to do what is left without using keys and values and hand crafting the final object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is

```
 { item: enhanced }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a key with desired name and put the value,

```js
let inside = {
  description: 'some text'
};

let field = {
  fielda: 'a',
  fieldb: 'b'
}

let enhanced = { item : {...inside,...field} }

console.log(enhanced)
```

(Note: This won't work on MS Edge)

Comment: @ScottHunter on my machine it is working fine i am not getting any error ? can you please tell me what error you're getting ??

Comment: Using MS Edge: {
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}

Comment: @ScottHunter [Edge](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Browser_compatibility) doesn't support spread syntax in object literals